# Event hub input size data is three time more in output size when reading using stream analytics

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

when i ingest 100 KB data file in event hub, when i read data from event hub using streaming analytic output file size is three times bigger than  input file.

Please confirm

Comment: the output and input size is not match, i am writing data into azure data lake

Comment: hi all, is any body face this issue

Comment: How did you configure the `Event Serialization Format` (JSON, CSV or Avro) and `Format` properties when you configuring the Event Hub input and the Data Lake Store output? And what is the query for you to generate the data for output.

Comment: hi, i am using input csv and output csv

Comment: I assumed that you could upload sample data from file or your event hub input and **Test** your query and download the results under the "JOB TOPOLOGY > Query" of your stream analytics job, then you could manually upload to your data lake folder to isolate this issue.

Comment: Can you please check if the output contains additional system fields that contribute to the size?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and as was investigating that, the input count (by byte and size) was multiplied by partition factors.
the partitions were created and mapped as inputs (we have only 2 inputs), but when you will see your job diagram - click **...** and select expand partitions.
Per attached picture our IoT hub input is expanded to **20** partitions.

[image: Two inputs seen as a multiple partitions]